# ImageButton doesn't change image OnClick

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton

I am new to the Android Studio so please excuse wierd coding. I wanted to start flash with the image button click, so started click listener and there are images in my drawing folder, but image remains the same:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fenjer);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
    {
        camera = camera.open();
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        isFlash = true;

    }
   imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(isFlash)
            {
            if(!isOn)
            {
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.startPreview();
                isOn = true;

            }
              else
                {
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isOn = false;

            }
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Fenjer.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Error...");
                builder.setMessage("Flash is not avaiable on this device...");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();

                }
            });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();


            }

        }
    });


}
```

The XML file:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/off"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="73dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="158dp" />
```